# Show files that are in a databse on page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've written a file upload in my asp.net mvc project, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the items out of the database to display on the page.

This is my controller which should pull the files from the database:

```
//upload
public static bool HasFile( this HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    return (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) ? true : false;
}

public FileContentResult GetFile(int id)
{
    SqlDataReader rdr; byte[] fileContent = null;
    string mimeType = "";
    string fileName = "";
    const string connect = @"Server=serverconnectioninfo";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
    {
        var qry = "SELECT FileContent, MimeType, FileName FROM FileStore WHERE ID = @ID";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
        conn.Open();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            rdr.Read();
            fileContent = (byte[])rdr["FileContent"];
            mimeType = rdr["MimeType"].ToString();
            fileName = rdr["FileName"].ToString();
        }
    }
    return File(fileContent, mimeType, fileName);
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<!--File Upload-->
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#detailsaccordion" href="#panelsix">
                Project Files
            </a>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="panelsix" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("", "CollaborativeProjects", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {

                    <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" /><br />
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End File Upload-->
```

Thank you.

Comment: What type of file? Image? Text File? Media? Think about how would you dislpay each of those file types on you page if they were a local resource instead of from a database and work from there.

Comment: they would be images or text files.  I'm unsure how to approach this from pulling it in from a db

Comment: Do you want a link to the text file (.txt? or MSWord?) or do you want to display it "in place" on the web page?

Comment: Displaying it in place on the web page would be cool

Answer (score 0):

You could save the file on the server and then provide a link to it. 
e.g.

```
<img src='@Url.Content("../../Content/Images/myimage.jpg")' alt="">
```

I would do the same for the text file.

If you really want to display the text file in place on the web page, I would read the content of the text file to a string variable and dump to html.
e.g.

```
...
<div class="panel-body">
    @Model.MyStringVariable
</div>
...
```

Note: just beware of reusing file names! I normally do not save blobs to the database. I save them to the file system and store the location and links/ids/keys etc in the database. This eliminates the problem of reusing file names and overhead with extracting from database.